# How to convert many words with no commas between them to a vector with a single algorithm?

Tags: r, vector, quotation-marks

Let's say I have the following words (but thousands of them) and there are no commas between them :

```
Hello Hi How Hide Hold Hear
```

and I want to convert them into a vector called H_words

```
H_words = c("Hello", "Hi", "How", "Hide", "Hold", "Hear")
```

How can we make that with a single and simple algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

```
words = "Hello, Hi, How, Hide, Hold, Hear"
H_words = strsplit(words, ", ")[[1L]]
H_words
# [1] "Hello" "Hi"    "How"   "Hide"  "Hold"  "Hear"
```

Comment: yes thanks. but in another scenario let's say that there are no commas between the words. How can we handle this issue in that case ?